# How to set a region for Azure Storage

Tags: azure

I have Azure SQL Databases located in North Central US (selected as Region). I want to create an Azure Storage there too. The problem is I see only West US and East US in my choice when creating new one. I don't want to have latency and extra cost. 
Does anyone know how to handle this? Should I try to move my databases in East US, for example?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a bit to @Brent's answer: This is where you'll need to contact customer support, to see if your subscription can be enabled for storage in N. Central, to align with your SQL resources.

Comment: I was playing with the trial version. Now, I will check if MS support can help us.

Comment: MS support just called me and said the same - I need to create a new server and export-import the data there. The sevrers at few locations are capped for the new subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

Not all Windows Azure platform services are available in all regions currently (mix of factors). So your only option may be to relocate your database to another region.

Comment: Ouch! Did not know that. Good we are still in testing phase. Thanks Brent!

Answer (score 1):

If you got to https://windows.azure.com/ (old portal) and then Hosted Service Accounts, Storage and CDN Tab down the left and then click the New Storage account up the top then you should be able to create a new one in North Central US, I can...

Also your best option is to create affinity group and then use this affinity so every thing gets colocated together for you nice and easily.

You do have options to move the DB and create a new affinity group but I don't think you need to in this instance if North Central US meets your needs...

Comment: I get the same list of 6 regions, not the extended one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Free trial subscription may have a limited list of regions.

Also I noticed a bug in the [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), when it does not refresh regions drop-down list when subscription is changed. It works fine in the [new (beta) portal](https://portal.azure.com).